# Can i read multiple integers from single line of input in Java without using a loop

Tags: java, input, integer, line, stdout

I have a problem of finding a piece of code to read a bunch of integers into a list, i tried this but in vain:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a = in.readInts(); //in cannot be resolved
    StdOut.println(count(a)); //StdOut cannot be resolved
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: "in" is nothing, "stdOut" is noting , you also don't have a list, i don't understand what you're actually doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example code, see if it works for you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int amount = 3; // Amount of integers to be read, change it at will.
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input your numbers: ");

        int num; // integer will be stored in this variable.
        // List that will store all the integers.
        ArrayList<Integer> List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i) {
            num = reader.nextInt();
            List.add(num);
        }
        System.out.println(List);
    }
}
```

This code in console with input `1 2 3` yields:

```
Please input your numbers:
1 2 3 
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: Can I read multiple integers from a single line of input without using a loop?

A. With parallel processing, possibly yes; but with normal sequential processing, NO, there will always be a loop involved.

Q: Can I, however, without benefit of parallel processing, read multiple integers from a single line of input without using one of the **loop statements** `for`, `while`, or `do`?

A: YES, with streams.  But don't think that by eliminating the explicit loop *statement* you've eliminated the actual **loop itself**;  it's still there, just hidden away inside the stream machinery instead of clearly visible in your own code.